# Unit Testing an MVC Cache using Rhino Mocks, do I need to use HttpContext?

Tags: unit-testing, model-view-controller, mocking, rhino-mocks

I am trying to create a Unit Test for an MVC Cache.  Currently, I created a new MockRepository (CacheManager is the wrapper class), and I am trying to figure out why the Get function returns null.  My manager mentioned that he believes it has something to do with creating a mock HTTP context.

1. Do I need to use a mock HTTP Context to do a unit test with a cache using Rhino?
2. Is my current code correct, assuming that Get and Set actually do work as they are supposed to?
3. Can anyone explain to me how a cache works in this MVC context, so I can get a better understanding of coding?

```cs
       // ARRANGE
        MockRepository mocks = new MockRepository();
        CacheManager cache = mocks.Stub<CacheManager>();
        cache.initialize();

        String str = "world";

        // ACT
        cache.Add<String>("hello", str);
        String hi = cache.Get<String>("hello");

        // ASSERT
        Assert.AreEqual(str, hi);
```

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Do I need to use a mock HTTP Context to do a unit test with a cache using Rhino?

You might need to mock classes like HttpRequestMessage, but I don't think you've reached this point just yet.

> 2. Is my current code correct, assuming that Get and Set actually do work as they are supposed to?

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve (test). If you'd like to test the actual cache, that would be a system test (add into cache, then read from actual cache). However, you'd usually just want to get some input from your dependencies in order to be able to reach certain code paths in your sut (System Under Test) - the class you're testing.

This is how you can setup the cache mock to return something for a particular method call:

```
CacheManager cache = MockRepository.GenerateMock<CacheManager>();
cache
    .Stub(x => x.Get(Arg<String>.is.Anything))
    .Return("hello");
```

You could follow that up with something like

```
cache.AssertWasCalled(x => x.Get<Arg<String>.Matches("abc"));
```

or something along these line (alternatively you could just use "Expect" instead of "Stub").

> 3. Can anyone explain to me how a cache works in this MVC context, so I can get a better understanding of coding?

Doesn't seem like there's a particular MVC context regarding that cache - it's probably just a case easing the load on your application, of not wanting to hit the DB for each and every request, especially for data that might not change that often. You would store this data in memory/some 3rd party cache provider, which would return faster than your DB. You'd then invalidate this cache when the data changes.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question!  Yes, that is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for!  My get function returns null when I tested it, so I will certainly try out this code and let you know how it works!

Comment: I tried using that code, and it was like visual studio didn't recognize any of the dots or anything like that.  Any ideas on why that might be?

Comment: what kind of compilation errors do you get? could you post a screenshot?

Comment: I spoke with a few of my coworkers and all of them recommended not trying to unit test a cache because it requires an outside HTTP request that is ridiculous to try to mock.

Comment: you don't need to *test the cache*, but you'll probably run into situations where you *need* to *stub* the cache in order to (reach) test logic inside your code